# StyleCop Settings not appear in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017, stylecop

I installed `StyleCop` `NuGet` package, now I want to change few settings of `StyleCop`, but right click on solution menu doesn't appear `StyleCop Settings` block..

any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more detail on version of Visual Studio you're using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Have you gone through other posts like; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278387/implementing-stylecop-msbuild-from-nuget-package?rq=1 ?

Comment: Go to project references, find analyzers, right click on it and select Open Active Rule Set, then you can disable\enable rules if styleCop is installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> StyleCop Settings not appear in Visual Studio

The simple way is to download the [StyleCop installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop), then install it. Once you have done the installation, your Visual Studio should have a new command under the Tools menu:

[image: New StyleCop menu]

In Visual Studio this menu appears when you right click on your **Project** (do not right click the Solution). In that options menu there should be a menu item for **StyleCop Settings**:

[image]

The Settings.StyleCop file can be opened from the Explorer and edited through a GUI. If that doesn’t work, try dragging the Settings file onto an application called StyleCopSettingsEditor.exe which is installed in your StyleCop Program Files folder.

[image: StyleCop menu on Project]

Besides, if you still want to use NuGet Package Manager and Visual Studio 2017 you’ll want to refer to [John Vanderbeck’s solution](https://medium.com/@jwvanderbeck/hi-lucas-8fda3ff6d3cb) on the Unity Answers forum.

Comment: If I install that VSIX file, will it change the version of StyleCop I'm using?  I cannot go to a newer version, because a certain version is require on our servers, I need to use the same locally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-Click on Your project;
2. Add new item;
3. Look for Settings File

Done